# Exporting ellipsis function from dll

Tags: c++, arguments, export, ellipsis

Is it possible to export ellipsis(mutli arg) function?
Example

```
// dll function
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl LogText(const wchar_t* fmt, ...);

// application 
typedef int (__cdecl *LogText)(const wchar_t* fmt, ...);
LogText doLog;
doLog = (LogText) GetProcAddress( hDll, "LogText");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. For example, the C runtime DLL exports `printf`.

However, your code won't work as is, as it doesn't take into account [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows). For `__cdecl`, this means prepending an underscore in the call to `GetProcAddress`:

```
doLog = (LogText) GetProcAddress( hDll, "_LogText");
```